# XML request and response SSH

Tags: xml, ssh, winscp

Please forgive me if this is too broad of a question.

I am trying to understand this assignment I was given. I am supposed to choose a SSH client that would have a service that would request another service for XML data. In response, this other service would respond with XML. I chose WinSCP because I am using windows and i found a link that I think is relevant to my situation:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml#using

Right now I am trying ot wrap my head around the whole process.

On my computer I have a service(A) running. This service SSH with WinSCP to request data from another service(B). In response service(B) will send XML back to service(A). The main purpose of the SSH client is to bypass firewalls through information given by the user. I was wondering if WinSCP is appropriate for this job. If I am misunderstanding anything or just have no idea what I am talking about, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the XML logging feature of WinSCP is completely irrelevant to your task.

Other than that I'm not sure, if I understand your assignment.

It seems to me that all you need is to download an XML file from the server. For this, see the guide to [automating file transfers from SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

If I'm wrong, please try to explain, what do you mean by *"service(B) will send XML back to service(A)"*.